# delete/clear AD attribute value if attribute contains value like val*

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Good Day!

I want to clear a specific values of AD attribute which is called aaccountroles
the concept like this:
if this attribute "aaccountroles" contains values that start with "S4P any" which means S4P*, it should remove the values like this

screen of an attribute in AD

[image: aaccountroles]

import-csv -Path .\test.csv | foreach{Set-ADUser $_.sAMAccountName -Clear aaccountroles}

this script clear all values, but I want to clear specific values
my test.csv file [image: csv file]

and I tried to create this scrip:

import-csv -Path .\test.csv | foreach{Set-ADUser $_.sAMAccountName -Clear @{aaccountroles="S4P*"}

but it gave an error

Set-ADUser : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
Parameter name: System.Collections.Hashtable
At line:1 char:39

- ... v | foreach{Set-ADUser $_.sAMAccountName -Clear @{aaccountroles="S ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (test.user1:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Clear` parameter of `Set-ADUser` expects a **string** or **string array**, not a hashtable.

You need to first find the user that has that attribute like 'S4P*' and if found clear that property:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\test.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($_.sAMAccountName)' -and aaccountroles -like 'S4P*'" -Properties aaccountroles -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        Write-Host "Clearing the aaccountroles attribute for user $($user.Name)"
        $user | Set-ADUser -Clear aaccountroles
    }
}
```

<sup>Using `-Remove`, `-Add`, `-Replace` or `-Clear` with Set-ADUser, you must use the LDAP display name. I prefer to also use the correct LDAP casing, so if that property is called `aaccountRoles` (with capital R), it can help to do that here too</sup>

---

It wasn't clear to me you wanted to empty the attribute completely (as the above does) of just taking out the items starting with ''S4P'..

Assuming the `aaccountroles` is an **array**:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\test.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($_.sAMAccountName)' -and aaccountroles -like 'S4P*'" -Properties aaccountroles -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        $roles = @($user.aaccountroles | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' -and $_ -notlike 'S4P*' })
        if ($roles.Count) {
            Write-Host "Removing the 'S4P*' aaccountroles items for user $($user.Name)"
            $user | Set-ADUser -Replace @{aaccountroles = [string[]]$roles}
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Clearing the aaccountroles attribute for user $($user.Name)"
            $user | Set-ADUser -Clear aaccountroles
        }
    }
}
```

---

Assuming that attribute is a multiline **string**, not an array, you can do:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\test.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($_.sAMAccountName)' -and aaccountroles -like 'S4P*'" -Properties aaccountroles -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        # split the multiline string into an array and filter out the items that do not start with 'S4P'
        $roles = @($user.aaccountroles -split '\r?\n' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' -and $_ -notlike 'S4P*' })
        if ($roles.Count) {
            Write-Host "Removing the 'S4P*' aaccountroles items for user $($user.Name)"
            # rejoin the left over array items into a multiline string
            $newRoles = $roles -join [environment]::NewLine
            $user | Set-ADUser -Replace @{aaccountroles = $newRoles}
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Clearing the aaccountroles attribute for user $($user.Name)"
            $user | Set-ADUser -Clear aaccountroles
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hI Theo,
don't we show here sAMAccountName ?
how this script will find sAMAccountName  from a csv file?

Comment: @Jonibek Sorry, forgot all about that.. Edited the answer now.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your script cleard all values
I want to clear not all values but specific values that start with S4P*

Comment: @Jonibek Please see my edit

Comment: I got this error:

Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Replace'. The argument is null or an element of the argument collection contains a null value.
At line:6 char:37
+ ...    $user | Set-ADUser -Replace @{aaccountroles = [string[]]$roles}
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Comment: @Jonibek Sp, what **is** the type of `aaccountroles`. A string array or a (comma) delimited string ?? I edited again to make sure you only have array items that contain text AND do not start with 'S4P'. IF that attrubute is a delimited string, we need to do a little adjustment. Please let me know what's what.

Comment: Mr.Theo 
aaccountroles - it is "Multi-valued String Editor", I have provided the screesnshot of this attribute in my question
and your script is clearing all values

Comment: @Jonibek Thanks for the screenshot. Looking at that plus your explanation of the attribute, my latest edit should work. It will only clear all if no other item starting with S4P exists in the array.

Comment: No, it also cleared all values wirth S4P*

Comment: @Jonibek Aha, I get it I think. The type is not a string array, but instead a single multiline string. Please see the latest edit to use such object type. Of course, if you want to **keep** only values starting with 'S4P', then change `$_ -notlike 'S4P*'` into `$_ -like 'S4P*'` in the Where-Object clause

Comment: anyway it is clearing all values while I want to clear only the values, starting with "S4P*"

Comment: @Jonibek Ok, now it is your turn to show how you use the code I think.. I have shown what you need if the property is an array of strings and also what to do if it is a single, multiline string delimited by newline characters. If this is still not what it actually looks like, then show us what you get if you just retrieve the property with `Get-ADUser`

Comment: Theo, I have used your code and got this result :

Clearing the aaccountroles attribute for user tes user1
Clearing the aaccountroles attribute for user test user2    it is clearing all values

Comment: @Jonibek Do a test. Add `Write-Host "ObjectType: $($_.aaccountroles.GetType().FullName)"` directly underneath the line `if ($user) {` and comment out the rest. Then tell me what is shown. Since it is opened in ADUC in the `Multi-valued String Editor`, it must be a collection, just like property `proxyAddresses` for instance. My second code should then work

Comment: Hi Theo, I got this: 
ObjectType: 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:35
+ ...    Write-Host "ObjectType: $($_.aaccountroles.GetType().FullName)"
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: @Jonibek Ah, sorry, I have made a typo.. Instead of `$roles = @($_.aaccountroles` it should have been `$roles = @($user.aaccountroles`. Fixed that in the answer too.

Comment: Theo, thanks it worked as expected, it deleted all values starting with S4P*, but it stored the rest of the already existing data in one line/row while each data was in each line/row

Comment: Theo, it is ok now, your 2nd script removed all S4P* and kept the other values as they were, but the 3rd script removed all S4P* and kept the remaining data in one row, I think the solution was just to add this:  "$newRoles = $roles -join [environment]::NewLine"

Comment: @Jonibek No, use the second script that loops through the elements as array. The last one I was assuming the property could store a multiline string, but clearly that isn't the case and we're dealing with a collection (array) of values.